# npm package branding

Tags: coffeescript, npm, branding, browserify

I have written a library in CoffeeScript.

It is made to tie Backbone views with Backbone collections and models through Knockout view-models. It helps to easily develope admin web-interfaces, and i've used it in my project. Now it is time to open-source this package, but i stuck with name. Current name - "bbko" comes from BackBone + KnockOut, but it does not sound good does it?

I am not a native English speaker, so your help is appreciated.

P.S. I know, there is already a good alternative library - KnockBack. It is not the one i wrote )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need some name suggestions? How about one of the following:

1. knock-my-bone
2. backbone-mvvm
3. knockdown
4. power-knock
5. outback
6. back-boxing

You can also go the Substuck way and give your package a completely different name, for example:

1. Loot
2. front-party
3. sandwich
4. luckyboy
5. boxing
6. clown-fish

Ultimately, it doesn't matter how you name your module. If it's good people will use it, star in on NPM and GitHub and recommend it to other developers.

Comment: Щиро дякую за стiльки креативу! Цього менi вистачить ще на кiлька проектiв.

Comment: Oh, I saw it couple of days ago. Haven't tried it yet, though. Bare Knockout is more than enough for most of our usecases, and calling server-side with [`browser-request`](https://npmjs.org/package/browser-request) is easy.

Comment: Just curious: what do you use backbone for?

Comment: REST, abstraction, application architecture.
In my case application is rather Backbone-centric. Knockout is used for visualisation, and BackStage is communication layer between BB and KO.

Comment: In our case it's a bit different. We work with KO for almost 2 years in different projects and tend to build client-side code around Ko View Models. So far we've being writing synchronization logic ourselves. The amount of code required is surprisingly small and easy to test. However, we're looking at Backbone now for history support. It seems a bit slicker than PJAX, Sammy or History.js.

Comment: If you've been working with KO so long, I must ask you some more questions. Do you somehow separate "data-bind"s from HTML markup? Do you have any kind of stand-alone templates? Any reusable UI components for KO?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22183/discussion-between-andrew---and-jsmarkus)